# Understanding Pointcloud2 data

Tags: pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to understand the pointcloud2 data extracted from a bag file. The contents of one sample message is as follows:

```
header: 
  seq: 0
  stamp: 
    secs: 1317022486
    nsecs: 689719915
  frame_id: "velo_link"
height: 1
width: 119597
fields: 
  - 
    name: "x"
    offset: 0
    datatype: 7
    count: 1
  - 
    name: "y"
    offset: 4
    datatype: 7
    count: 1
  - 
    name: "z"
    offset: 8
    datatype: 7
    count: 1
  - 
    name: "i"
    offset: 12
    datatype: 7
    count: 1
is_bigendian: False
point_step: 16
row_step: 1913552
data: [131, 64, 23, 66, 223, 79, 141, 61, 201, 118, 190, 63, 236, 81, 184, 62, 31, 133, 25, 66, 184, 30, 5, 62, 96, 229, 192, 63, 61, 10, 87, 62, 74, 140, 26, 66, 55, 137, 129, 62, 74, 12, 194, 63, 61, 10, 87, 62, 45, 178, 26, 66, 0, 0, 192, 62, 14, 45, 194, 63, 82, 184, 158, 62, 240, 39, 27, 66, 219, 249, 254, 62, 33, 176, 194, 63, 236, 81, 56, 62, 100, 59, 32, 66, 147, 24, 36, 63, 39, 49, 200, 63, 143, 194, 117, 62, 166, 155, 32, 66, 47, 221, 68, 63, 117, 147, 200, 63, 0, 0, 0, 0, 190, 31, 35, 66, 57, 180, 104, 63, 150, 67, 203, 63, 143, 194, 245, 61, 213, 248, 40, 66, 14, 45, 146, 63, 252, 169, ...................................]
```

I m just trying to match the numbers here.

data [ ] has 1913552 number of elements in it.

row_step says there is 1913552 bytes data in data array.

There are 4 elements per point: x, y, z, i. Each of 1 byte.

Thus the total number of point clouds in this captured message is: 1913552/4 = 478388.

But according to explanation given [here](http://docs.ros.org/en/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/PointCloud2.html), "If the cloud is unordered, height is 1 and width is the length of the point cloud.". That is width denotes the total number of point clouds in the message. But above calculated total number of point clouds (478388) is not matching with width(119597) given in message information. Please explain this mismatch/misunderstanding.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/373094/understanding-pointcloud2-data/) by [SurajJadhav](https://answers.ros.org/users/71239/surajjadhav/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2021-03-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> There are 4 elements per point: x, y, z, i. Each of 1 byte.

I think this is where you're getting confused.  The `data` elements are not `x, y, z` coordinates; they are bytes of data.  The other parameters indicate how to read them.  In this case `point_step = 16` indicates each point is 16 bytes, so each of its 4 components (`fields`) would be 4 bytes, which makes sense as they are 32-bit floats (`datatype: 7`; see [sensor_msgs/PointField](http://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/PointField.html)).

> width: 119597

As you said, this indicates that you have 119597 points in your cloud.  `row_step * height` is the length of `data` in bytes (1913552 as you noted), but each point is 16 bytes long.  Therefore, the number of points in `data` is `1913552 / 16 = 119597` as previously indicated.

---

Originally posted by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) with karma: 1421 on 2021-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SurajJadhav](https://answers.ros.org/users/71239/surajjadhav/) on 2021-03-03**:
Thanks Tryan for pointing out the misunderstanding. After this I went on to search ros_numpy.point_cloud2.pointcloud2_to_array(msg) method which provided me the required point cloud data.

**Comment by [Petros ADLATUS](https://answers.ros.org/users/99003/petros-adlatus/) on 2022-05-20**:
@tryan can you tell me in relation to the question of @SurajJadhav what does it mean when data is: [0,0,0,0]. Means this, that der laser light do not hit a object and can return x,y,z and intensity for it?

**Comment by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) on 2022-05-21**:
@petros ADLATUS This should really be a separate question, but the short answer is: it depends...  [REP-117](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0117.html) says it should be:

- below min range: -Inf
- above max range: +Inf (likely no object)
- error: NaN
  However, Ouster for example, seems to use 0 as out of range.  My best advice is to find a user guide for your particular lidar.

**Comment by [Petros ADLATUS](https://answers.ros.org/users/99003/petros-adlatus/) on 2022-05-23**:
@tryan thank you for explanation, thats the point the LIDAR leaflet hasn't these information :/